# BigQuery / Shopify Order Data Query

Tags: shopify, google-bigquery

My order import from Shopify creates a new entry in BigQuery for every order if something has changed since the last import, this way you could see how the order properties change over time and not just the last import state. This also creates multiple entries in the table for the same order where the only unique part is the `_sdc_batched_at` and `sdc_sequence` values. I'm seeing sometimes as many as 30 entries of the same order.

#### Table schema...

```
order:
  order_number: Int
  fulfillments: Array
  _sdc_batched_at: DateTime
  _sdc_sequence: Int
```

#### What I've done...

I've created a partitioned table that essentially boils down to a subset of entries between a given date range and where fulfillments > 0

#### Initial Query to reduce dataset...

```
with orders as (
    select order_number, fulfillments, _sdc_batched_at, _sdc_sequence
    from `project.shopify.orders`
    where created_at between '2018-11-08' and '2018-11-15'
    and ARRAY_LENGTH(fulfillments) > 0
)
```

The problem...
I'm running into issues trying to use distinct or group by since fulfillments is an array and that throws things off. How do I write a query that will only return the latest order entry by `_sdc_batched_at` value?

#### Sample Data

```json
    [
    {
        "order_number": "5545",
        "fulfillments": [
        {
            "tracking_url": null,
            "id": "617029074993",
            "tracking_company": "ups",
            "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
        }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 02:46:21.270 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541817507934"
    },
    {
        "order_number": "5545",
        "fulfillments": [
        {
            "tracking_url": null,
            "id": "617029074993",
            "tracking_company": "ups",
            "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
        }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 03:16:16.606 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541819139795"
    },
    {
        "order_number": "5545",
        "fulfillments": [
        {
            "tracking_url": null,
            "id": "617029074993",
            "tracking_company": "ups",
            "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
        }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 03:46:12.704 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541821046476"
    },
    {
        "order_number": "5545",
        "fulfillments": [
        {
            "tracking_url": null,
            "id": "617029074993",
            "tracking_company": "ups",
            "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
        }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 04:16:07.952 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541822755508"
    },
    {
        "order_number": "2212",
        "fulfillments": [
            {
                "tracking_url": null,
                "id": "617029074993",
                "tracking_company": "ups",
                "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
            }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 03:46:12.704 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541821046476"
    },
    {
        "order_number": "2212",
        "fulfillments": [
            {
                "tracking_url": null,
                "id": "617029074993",
                "tracking_company": "ups",
                "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
            }
        ],
        "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 04:1:07.952 UTC",
        "_sdc_sequence": "1541822755508"
    }
    ]
```

#### Expected Result

Return only the latest entry by `_sdc_batched_at` value

```json
{
    "order_number": "5545",
    "fulfillments": [
    {
        "tracking_url": null,
        "id": "617029074993",
        "tracking_company": "ups",
        "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
    }
    ],
    "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 04:16:07.952 UTC",
    "_sdc_sequence": "1541822755508"
},
{
    "order_number": "2212",
    "fulfillments": [
        {
            "tracking_url": null,
            "id": "617029074993",
            "tracking_company": "ups",
            "tracking_number": "Z1234567890"
        }
    ],
    "_sdc_batched_at": "2018-11-10 04:1:07.952 UTC",
    "_sdc_sequence": "1541822755508"
}
```

Comment: provide simplified example of your data as well as expected result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY _sdc_batched_at DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM `project.shopify.orders` t
GROUP BY order_number
```

obviously you can add all needed for your WHERE clause

Comment: I'm going to work through some scenarios to make sure this works across different datasets before marking as solved. Looks promising so far.

Comment: sure :o) good luck and let us know if any issues with using this approach

Comment: Marked as solved. I'll have a follow-up question tomorrow if I can't figure it out on my own. Essentially my end goal with this data is to get a 1-to-1 list of order_number & tracking_number. Since one order could have many tracking numbers I need to dig into the array of fulfillment, grab each one, extract the tracking_number and then use its parent number as the order_number value.

Comment: sure. if your follow up question(s) will be within the scope of current one  - just use comments. But if this will be new one  - please post it as a new question :o)

Comment: I'll make it a new question. It is related but should probably be a new question for future searches.